# SQL Calculations on 3 Table Inner Join

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join

I have three tables: Stock, Orderline and Order. I have a Total column in the Order table which I want to contain a sum of the orderlines for each order. The Orderline table consists of Order_id, Stock_id and Qty, the Stock table has Stock_id and Price. I can filter the Stock_ids associated with each Order_id and display the Qty for each, and I think I need to use an inner join to calculate the cost of each order through summing the price of each Stock_id and multiplying it by both the Qty in the Orderline table and the price in the Stock table, but I'm not sure where to start with this. I also want to have this added to the Total column within the database when calculated for each Order_id and don't know how to do that either. I'm using SQLite3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Order Table:
order_id, order_total, order_datetime

Orderline Table:
order_id, stock_id, qty

Stock Table:
stock_id, stock_price, stock_name

Comment: It would probably help to show the tables with column headers and some sample rows

Comment: I'm not sure how to use tables on here, and it's difficult to show them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic query with `INNER JOIN` grouped by the order id to give you the total by order. You can do whatever filters you need then in a `WHERE` clause before the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
    O.order_id,
    SUM(S.stock_price * OL.qty) AS [Total]
FROM Order O
    INNER JOIN Orderline OL
        ON OL.order_id = O.order_id
    INNER JOIN Stock S
        ON S.stock_id = OL.stock_id
GROUP BY
    O.order_id
```

While sqlite doesn't support computed columns, you would have 2 options:

1. Create a column added to the `Order` table to store the value of the total, then create a trigger on `Orderline` and `Stock` tables to recalculate the total for the modified records.
2. Convert the query above into a separate view, then do an `INNER JOIN` from the created view to your `Order` table whenever you need the totals.

Comment: Great, thanks for that. I assume that creating a trigger will only add totals to new data?

Comment: For full accuracy, you'd need triggers on INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE so that on any modification to stock prices or order line quantities would ensure your `Total` is updated accordingly for the modified stocks/orders. If you need to lock in what the price was at time of order, then I'd put a `Price` field on the Orderline table and make the trigger only on Orderline and calculation ignore the `Stock` table in favor of only the qty and price in Orderline.